# Webform - User to edit submission (admin can close)

Tags: webforms

I have a webform that a authenticated user can submit. Where is the page for the authenticated user to re-edited their submission? I can't find it?

I also want to extend a another function. I want to have the ability to close a submission (so the authenticated user) can't re-edit it anymore.

Any suggestions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You have to view your submission and click on edit to update. Remember you can only edit your own submission.